# How to lock a buffer which needs to be write-only?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, new-operator

Is it possible to overload the `new` operator to allocate a bigger buffer with read-only memory on both sides to detect memory overflow, and how could I make that memory read-only?

linux + gcc

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand.  Can you break the description down into more detailed sentences?

Comment: I've rephrased the question with what I think you're trying to ask, can you check and make sure it is what you're trying to ask?

Comment: If @Kevin's edit is appropriate, I think what you want is identical to the feature set that `libefence.so` (Electric Fence) provides.  `ef ./test_prog && EF_PROTECT_BELOW=1 ef ./test_prog`

Comment: @kevin thank you for you help, it is what I'm tring to ask ,sorry for my unclear describle before.

Answer (score 7):

Try [Electric Fence](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libefence).  Its effect is global to your process' heap, but if your program accesses memory correctly it should not have any (unwanted) ill effect.